# OS X building gsl (GNU Scientific Library)

Tags: c++, compilation, gsl

I'm trying to build the gsl library on OS X. I got the gsl-1.0 from [here](http://ftp.download-by.net/gnu/gnu/gsl/).

I rand `./configure` in the folder followed my `make`.

Once I ran make, I got this:

```
In file included from results.c:30:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include/varargs.h:25:4: error: "Please use <stdarg.h> instead of <varargs.h>"
  #error "Please use <stdarg.h> instead of <varargs.h>"
   ^
results.c:70:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'va_start' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      va_start (ap);
      ^
results.c:73:7: warning: implicit declaration of function 'va_end' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      va_end (ap);
      ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [results.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive-am] Error 2
```

I looked in the `...include/varargs.h` file and found:

```
/*===---- varargs.h - Variable argument handling -------------------------------------===
*
* Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
* of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
* in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
* to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
* copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
* furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
*
* The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
* all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
*
* THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
* IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
* FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
* AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
* LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
* OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
* THE SOFTWARE.
*
*===-----------------------------------------------------------------------===
*/
#ifndef __VARARGS_H
#define __VARARGS_H
  #error "Please use <stdarg.h> instead of <varargs.h>"
#endif
```

Have I done something very wrong? Can I fix this?

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Did you try to actually *read* the message and try to understand what it says?

Comment: When you write it like that, I feel that there is something obvoius that I've missed. I have looked in the file that causes it 'results.c' and I could just change it there, it just seems to be an inpropper way around it?

Comment: I re-read your question, and I take it that this `results.c` is not your file, but from the library you're trying to build? Then I'm sorry if I sounded a little harsh. Yes you *could* of course edit the file, but like you said it's not really an appropriate solution. A better one would be to try and look for a later version of the library. If there's no later version available, and the library seems abandoned (so you can't add a bug report) then there's not much choice but to edit the file yourself.

Comment: Ah alright. No worries, it wasn't clear that results.c was not written by me, I should have stated that.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use such an old version of GSL? The one you are trying to compile is from 2001! The latest is version 1.16. To make your life a little easier have you thought of using a package manager such as [macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install it for you.

Comment: I got the one from homebrew. But I tried to install [mdptetris](http://mdptetris.gforge.inria.fr/doc/index.html) but when I run the configure file inside the donwloaded folder, I get the following error: `checking for main in -lgslcblas... no \n error: The GNU Scientific Library (libgsl) is required`. So I just assumed that the one from brew was not suited?

Comment: Looks like the configure script isn't finding the version of GSL that homebrew has installed. Try telling it where it is manually to do this try running ``./configure LDFLAGS=`gsl-config --libs` CFLAGS=`gsl-config --cflags` ``

Comment: Garh, It feels like I'm sooo close! now I get `configure: error: unrecognized option: -lgsl`. Sorry to ask so many questions, I'm quite lost in this : /

Comment: Ok that one was my fault sorry! I missed a pair of quotes it should be ``./configure LDFLAGS="`gsl-config --libs`" CFLAGS="`gsl-config --cflags`" ``